# SQL query with NOT EXISTS to determine if another attribute has certain values

Tags: sql, subquery, exists

Struggling with a SQL query of mine here. 
I have a table:

APPS(id, game)
Where id is the primary key.

What I was trying to do is show all the id's who use at least all the games that the person with the id "Tim" does. 
I have a query that works, and returns what i need it to, but i cobbled it together from forums. 
So what I'd really like is a quick and basic rundown of how the query works. Heavy detail isn't necessary, as i understand most of the terminology, but just what the query does, and how it determines the correct records.

My query is:

```
SELECT id
FROM APPS X
WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT *
      FROM APPS Y
      WHERE id='Tim' AND NOT EXISTS
           (SELECT *
            FROM APPS Z
            WHERE Z.id = A.id AND Z.id = Y.id));
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Edit: The query works fine, but what i was after is how it works and how it returns the records it does.

Comment: I can see it has been heavily inspired by relational algebra and its double negatives to calculate FOR-ALL, and there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: `A.id` on the last name looks undefined to me. Is it supposed to be `X.id`?

Comment: I don't think so. Well, it's returning everything it's supposed to, so i figure it's correct.

Comment: Is that a subquery to something which defines a table `A`?

Comment: It seems to me the query is ignoring the `game` column and thus cannot work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The query works fine, but what i was after is how it works and how it
>   returns the records it does.

Right, so you've hit the problem called Relational Division.  Joe Celko has written a [good article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) about that.

The query that you posted is really strange:

```
WHERE Z.id = A.id AND Z.id = Y.id
```

In relational division, the innermost `not exists` query has two equality statements for different columns.  For example, from Joe Celko's post:

```
WHERE (PS1.pilot_name = PS2.pilot_name)
      AND (PS2.plane_name = Hangar.plane_name)
```

Comparing `pilot_name` and `plane_name` makes sense, where comparing `id` twice makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! The article explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT prefiltered.id
FROM (select count(distinct game) games from apps where id='Tim') tim
join (select id from apps
      where id<>'Tim'
      group by id
      having count(distinct game) >= tim.games) prefiltered
JOIN apps a on a.id = 'Tim'
JOIN apps b on b.id = prefiltered.id and b.game = a.game
group by prefiltered.id
having count(distinct b.game) = tim.games
```

A bit wordier, and could be overkill for small tables.  The idea is to pre-count the games Tim has, and to quickly pre-filter for ids with at least that many games.  Only then is the full table consulted matching Tim's games to the filtered ids'.

Comment: Ohhhh. I like you way of doing it. I think the NOT EXISTS were getting to me :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Please provide colname as per common between table :

SELECT id
FROM APPS X
WHERE colname NOT in
     (SELECT colname
      FROM APPS Y
      WHERE id='Tim' AND colname NOT in
           (SELECT colname
            FROM APPS Z
            WHERE Z.id = A.id AND Z.id = Y.id));
```

Comment: colname is 'id'. At least that's what i think you are asking for.

Comment: The query works, I just dont understand how. I was after 'how does the wuery return the records it does". But thank you so far! :)

Comment: you are not provide colname in where cluse,,,

Comment: Im not asking for the query to be re-written. I was after how exactly MY query works. But thank you.